# Can I permanently skip the intro when starting Kohan?

Tags: kohan

Is there any way to permanently skip (ie. disable) the introductory movie?  It's only one extra <kbd>Esc</kbd> keypress, but I need my Kohan *now!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In the `Data` directory of your Kohan installation (if you purchased Kohan [via Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/11141/), this will be in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\steamapps\common\Kohan Ahrimans Gift\Data`), open the file `multimedia.ini`.

Comment out the line that reads:

```
Movie_01 = TimeGate_Logo.bik
```

such that it instead reads:

```
;Movie_01 = TimeGate_Logo.bik
```

The opening cinematic will henceforth be skipped.